# fitz.fitz.FileDataError: cannot open document

Tags: pdf

```
def read_pdf(path:  str)  -> str:
doc = fitz.open(path)  
txt = ""
for page in doc:
    txt += page.get_text("text")
return txt
```

I get the error fitz.fitz.FileDataError: cannot open document. Could some one help? Thank you in anticipation.